# How to see if two polymorphic objects are equal?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

How to see if two polymorphic objects are equal? For example

```
struct A {};

struct A1 : public A
{
    int i;
    bool operator==(A1 const& other) const { return i == other.i; }
};

struct A2 : public A
{
    float f;
    bool operator==(A2 const& other) const { return f == other.f; }
};

bool isEqual(A const& x, A const& y)
{
    if (typeid(x) != typeid(y))
        return false;

    ... // Then how to compare when they have same type. Any way to cast them 
        // to their dynamic types by typeid or others
}
```

Comment: Have a look at visitor pattern. You need to implement something like that or use `dynamic_cast` along with `virtual bool equals(base const & other) const`.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code that's already in your question?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Since there is no == for A1+A2, it would just not compile, so you can safely compare x and y, no ? The question is not very clear to me.

Comment: @quantdev Their static type would be A and A if used polymorphic. I.e. you have some `vector<A*>` to store A1s and A2s, and the question now is: how can you compare two such objects (not their pointers) with an overridden comparison?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for.  If they have the same type, do you want to check for binary equal objects (i.e. all content bit to bit equal) ? Or do you want to use a subset of member data for the comparison (if there is some tmp data which is not relevant for the comparison) ?   Or are you looking for a polymorphic equal ?

Comment: Bear in mind that polymorphic comparisons are generally broken by design. You can do what you want, it just would not be the right thing to do (in most cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the "Curiously Recurring Template" pattern but with a helper class in between the base and the derived classes.

First, add a pure-virtual `operator==` in your base class `A`.

Write a helper class responsible for redirecting the comparison to the dynamic type class. This helper class has two template type parameters: a base class and a concrete class; this class should derive from the base class:

```
template<typename Base, typename Derived>
struct PolymorphicComparable : public Base {
    ...
};
```

Within this class, you implement `operator==` (if `Base==A` later, this will be an override):

```
bool operator==(const Base &other) const {
    // first check if the dynamic types match
    if (typeid(other) != typeid(Derived))
        return false;

    // cast to the concrete types; thanks to the check above this is safe
    const Derived & a = static_cast<const Derived&>(*this);
    const Derived & b = static_cast<const Derived&>(other);

    // redirect to Derived::operator==(Derived)
    return a == b;
}
```

Now, your subclasses of `A` do not directly subclass `A` but rather the above class (this is the "Curiously Recurring Template"), and each implement their own `operator==` with no additional code required:

```
struct A1 : public PolymorphicComparable<A,A1>
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    int i;

    bool operator==(const A1 &other) const {
        return i == other.i;
    }
};
```

Note: the helper class template is required only **once**, not only once for each base class but once in your whole code-base even if you have multiple base classes you want to compare based on the polymorphic type.

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/Q1kOny)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a virtual member function in `A` for the `operator==` function. Implement `operator!=` using the `operator==`.

   ```
   struct A
   {
       virtual bool operator==(A const& other) const = 0;
       bool operator!=(A const& other) const
       {
           return !(*this == other);
       }
   };
   ```
2. Implement the `operator==` function in the concrete class and add the necessary checks.

   ```
   struct A1 : public A
   {
       int i;
       virtual bool operator==(A const& other) const
       {
          // Do dynamic cast to make sure that other is of type A1.
          A1 const* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<A1 const*>(&other);
          if ( otherPtr == NULL )
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
             return i == otherPtr->i;
          }
       }
   };
   ```

**Update**

If `A` has data that need to be taken into consideration when comparing two objects...

```
struct A
{
    virtual bool operator==(A const& other) const
    {
       return (j == other.j);
    }

    bool operator!=(A const& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    int j;
};

struct A1 : public A
{
    int i;
    virtual bool operator==(A const& other) const
    {
       if ( !(A::operator==(other)) )
       {
          return false;
       }

       // Do dynamic cast to make sure that other is of type A1.
       A1 const* otherPtr = dynamic_cast<A1 const*>(&other);
       if ( otherPtr == NULL )
       {
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
          return i == otherPtr->i;
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: That is very simplified. It *assumes* there are no data in the base hierarchy to be compared.

Comment: @Nawaz: It's true this answer doesn't show that, but the approach still works when there are multiple subobjects to compare.  Base subobjects get compared by calling the base `A::operator==(other)`.

Comment: @Nawaz, Please see my update. It's exactly what was suggested by Ben Voigt.